# Webistrano stuck on deploy:update_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, webistrano

I've been trying to set up webistrano on one of our servers. Everything went well, until I tried deploying my set up. Webistrano is currenlty set up to live on the test server, so I want it to deploy to 127.0.0.1

The configuration contains valid user, webistrano, that should have access to 
/home/webistrano/.subversion/servers

the password for that user is correct. Could someone shed some light as to what might be going wrong with it?

```
*** SSH options: setting ssh_port to: 22
*** LOCAL SCM ERROR: svn: warning: Can't open file '/home/webistrano/.subversion/servers': Permission denied
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
  * executing "svn checkout -q --username webistrano --password XXXXXXXX --no-auth-cache  -r27687 http://server.com/repos/server/clients/site/trunk     /var/www/vhosts/server.com/releases/20121001183038 && (echo 27687 > /var/www/vhosts/server.com/releases/20121001183038/REVISION)"
    servers: ["127.0.0.1"]
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/server.com/releases/20121001183038; true"
servers: ["127.0.0.1"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: 127.0.0.1 (Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - connect(2))
*** connection failed for: 127.0.0.1 (Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - connect(2))
```

debugging with 
`puts system('id')` in `deployer.rb` returns

```
uid=500(webistrano) gid=500(webistrano) groups=500(webistrano) context=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
```

and `ls -all /home/webistrano` returns:

`drwxrwxr-x. 3 webistrano webistrano 4096 Sep 27 16:59 .subversion`

ls -all /home/webistrano/.subversion returns:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 3 webistrano webistrano 4096 Oct  1 20:02 .
drwx------. 4 webistrano webistrano 4096 Oct  1 22:14 ..
drwx------. 6 webistrano webistrano 4096 Sep 27 16:59 auth
-rw-rw-r--. 1 webistrano webistrano 6866 Sep 27 16:59 config
-rw-rw-r--. 1 webistrano webistrano 4276 Sep 27 16:59 README.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 webistrano webistrano 7674 Oct  1 20:02 servers
```

Which shows that servers should be fully readable by everyone?
What's going on?

Comment: What happens if you `su` to that user and try to look at `/home/webistrano/.subversion/servers`?

Comment: Hey Ben. I can fully edit / view it without a problem. I'm very confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue with Passenger.
Phusion Passenger is supposed to run as the user who owns conf/environment.conf (which in my case was webistrano). Displaying the user id also showed webistrano, but if I changed it to run as nobody, the svn error stopped appearing. I was unable to svn export the code though, probably because nobody does not have a home directory.

I ended up running webistrano through **mongrel**, and starting it by doing:

```
$ su - webistrano
```

to make sure that the correct home environment is loaded and all the permissions are correct.
It works perfect now . Hope this helps somebody